# Android - Drag & Drop Image view (Drop Zone only in Restricted Area)

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-imageview

I am doing a drag and drop `imageview` in my project. It works fine. But I want the `imageview` to be dropped in particular `Layout` only. For instance, if I have id->l1 for a linear layout and id->l2 for another linear layout. The Image view can be dragged into both the layouts but the drop zone must within first linear layout (with id->11). The second linear layout with id->l2 must not be an drop zone for the dragged image view.

I'd appreciate insight on how to implement this.

Comment: http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/drag-and-drop-ui-element/